# QA-C: license file

Tags: qa-c

I'm trying to run QA-C 7.2 on a Nightly Build that I program using Python.
It does run but the problem I encounter is, that I cannot save the license file configuration settings because IM not a 'license admin'. Hence, everytime I run QA-C it requires me to browse to the license.dat 
Does anyone know a way around this, for example passing the license file configuration (eg path2license_dat) as a parameter when I call the exe? Or somehow saving this information?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it works when setting the environment variable LM_LICENSE_FILE to the path to license.dat